# Отстутствие некоторых методов в QtCore - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Проблема заключается в отсутствии некоторых методов в классе QtCore.
Для примера, в данном коде, я не могу использовать метод `label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)`
поскольку он мне по какой то причине недоступен, хотя в документации есть и `AlignCenter`, и `AlignHCenter & AlignVCenter`

вот полный код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("app")
window.resize(300, 100)
window.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
window.show()

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setText(str(window.windowOpacity()))
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
window.setLayout(vbox)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. У вас лишняя закрывающая скобка `label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))`. 2. Покажите изображение, которое вы получаете.

Comment: очень глупо, но это и было ошибкой. Но меня путает то что в VS Code когда я пишу точку после Qt, мне не предлагает на выбор AlignCenter

Comment: @S.Nick вопрос неточно составил

Comment: `VS Code` - это ваш выбор. А запускать приложения на исполнение надо из  `CMD/консоли/терминала`  и вы всегда получите реальную ошибку, если ошибка у вас действительно есть.

Answer (score 1):

Ситуацию с подсказками можно решить установкой пакета [PyQt5-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/). Пакет содержит заглушки для многих (хотя и не всех) методов **PyQt5** с аннотациями типов по [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). **VS Code** (а точнее, расширение *Python Language Server*) использует их при формировании списка автодополнения.